# Failed to load 'CrystalReport' from Crystl32.OCX

Tags: crystal-reports, ocx

Whenever I try to run this application (I didn't write it) that uses Crystl32.OCX, I get the error...

```
Run-time error '372':

Failed to load control 'CrystalReport' from Crystl32.OCX.  Your version of
Crystl32.OCX may be outdated.  Make sure you are using the version of the
control that was provided with your application.
```

For a long time, I was getting an error about Crystl32.OCX could not be found, but I ultimately managed to register it. However, it's not working properly now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reloading the Crystl32.ocx file and installing it in the path. C:\Windows\System\crystl32.ocx or C:\Windows\SysWow64\crystl32.ocx and you can download the update file this link ---> https://www.ocxme.com/files/crystl32_ocx